# POWER BI: Is it possible to create a user input checkbox in a report

Tags: powerbi

I have developed a Power BI report, in which there is a list of drivers.
By clicking on a driver, the user can drill through to the next page which shows a report on the driver with various infos such as his accident history, his telemetry history, speeding alert heatmaps etc.
This page will be used by the driver's supervisors. The supervisor will print this page out and ask for the driver to sign it.
I wanted to include somewhere in my report **a place where the supervisor could register that he printed a report for driver X with a datestamp.**
This way, I would automate the control of reports being printed by filling out a table.

Is this possible through Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

Not easily possible. In general, Power BI is designed for information to flow from the data systems to the end-user and not the other way around. There are some custom visuals that can do that sort of thing but that's definitely not standard built-in stuff.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Alexis! Do you know of any custom visuals that can do this or something close?

Comment: A Power App data input section that will feed back to a database to register the confirmation, should be able to do it

Comment: Ahh... I did some research on that and I believe you are correct... Although, today, I am using a free account and don't have access to Apps. I am trying to get a pro account at my company but it's been one heck of a political ride...